# get the present value of dropdown when change

Tags: c#, events

I have a DropDown that is automatically filled up when another DropDown value is changed:

```
private void cbWidth_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.InvokeEventHandler(this.AutoFillDropdown);
    }
```

For example: The value of the 1st DropDown is 1 then the 2nd DropDown is also 1.

When I change the value of the 1st DropDown to 2 the 2nd DropDown remains to 1 then change the 1st DropDown to 3 the 2nd DropDown is 2.

The 2nd DropDown only gets the value before change. I need the value of the DropDown after the change so that the 2 DropDown are always similar.

Comment: Can you post the code for AutoFillDropdown?  Are you using the correct event?  Is this a `leave` event when you should be using some kind of `change` event?

Comment: my problems is i don't know what event to used. to trigger this **this.InvokeEventHandler(this.AutoFillDropdown);**

Answer (score 0):

You could do a

```
ComboBoxEdit1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     comboBox2.ValueMember = Convert.ToString(comboBox1.SelectedValue+=1);

}
```